# Referring to module types defined in toplevel files

Tags: ocaml

In OCaml, if your project has a file called code.ml you can refer to it in other files using the module name Code. I was wondering if you defined an .mli file if you could refer to the signature it defines in a similar way. For example if you had a file called wow.mli and you could have another file with the declaration

```
module Func(St : Wow) = struct ... end
```

Is there a way to do something along those lines?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
module Func(St: module type of Wow) = struct ... end
```

In detail here's what I did:

```
$ cat wow.mli
val f : int -> int
$ cat m.ml
module Func (St: module type of Wow) = struct let f x = St.f x end
$ ocamlopt -c wow.mli
$ ocamlopt -c m.ml
```

Comment: If I do "module type FuncT = module type of Func" in another file it claims their is a signature mismatch.

Comment: (If you want help you'll have to show your code I think.)